# unable to delete duplicate article From Developer console Anonymous Window

Tags: soql, list, knowledge, articles

My profile is System Administrator and have access knowledge object and all the permission assigned like edit,delete,view,view all. I am able to 
delete duplicate article manually but when i am trying to do with soql it not allowing to delete and its showing error message

> DML operation Delete not allowed on List

```
List<Knowledge__kav> fullList = [Select Id, title From Knowledge__kav where 
           publishstatus='Draft' and language='en_US' and createddate= today limit 200];
Set<String> orderObj = new Set<String>(); 
List<Knowledge__kav> dupList = new List<Knowledge__kav>();

for(Knowledge__kav o : fullList){
     if(orderObj.contains(o.title)){
        dupList.add(o);
     }
     else{
          orderObj.add(o.title);
     }
}

Integer c = dupList.size();
system.debug(c);

if(dupList.size()>0){
   delete dupList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge Object is very special object...you can not simply delete as other object. There is special class to perform DML on Knowledge Objects: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_knowledge_kbManagement.htm#apex_KbManagement_PublishingService_methods

There is method to delete draft articles and many more!!...

```
List<Article__kav> ar = [ Select Id,knowledgeArticleId, title From Article__kav where 
           publishstatus='Draft' and language='en_US' limit 1];

String articleVersionId = ar[0].knowledgeArticleId;
KbManagement.PublishingService.deleteDraftArticle(articleVersionId);
```